# ERROR: native-run was not found on your PATH. (Ionic 4)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, ionic4

Out of nowhere, being able to deploy my app to android in the recent past I am now receiving this error when trying to run 'ionic cordova run android'

```
[ERROR] native-run was not found on your PATH. Please install it globally: npm i -g native-run
```

When I run 'ionic info' under Utilities I see cordova-res and native-run are installed, but still this error recurs, every time.

**Sidenote**: '*npm i -g native-run*' does not resolve this issue, the error just recurs

Performing `ls /usr/local/lib/node_modules`
returns: 'ionic cordova npm' (no sign of native-run, which should be there)

Is there a way I can install it directly to that location? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For now, you try running the command like - `ionic cordova run android --native-run=false`. Note - This is not the solution, just a workaround.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this workaround, thank you for this.

Comment: I would try uninstalling and reinstalling `native-run`. If that doesn't work it might be a permissions issue.

Comment: Have tried this, and have tried running the command using sudo and still no suffice. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

you have to update your libraries using :

```sh
npm i -g native-run@latest
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this issue too.
Here is what I did to fix it.

1 - Run `ionic info` at the root of your Ionic project you should get something like.

```
Ionic:
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.4 (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.9.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:
   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 4 other plugins)

Utility:
   cordova-res : 0.6.0 
   native-run  : 0.2.8 

System:
   NodeJS : v10.16.3 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.9.0
   OS     : Linux 5.0
```

2 - Run `cd /usr/lib` (The directory where your Ionic CLI is installed) then you run `npm install native-run`.

3 - Run `ln -s /usr/lib/node_modules/native-run/bin/native-run /usr/bin/native-run` this will create a link to your binary file.

Then you should be good.

Comment: Trying step 2 I receive in console: "Missing write access to /usr/lib" followed by a lot of errors; utilising the sudo prefix does not resolve this issue.

Comment: Step 3 I am receiving in console "Operation not permitted" and "The operation was rejected by your operating system"

Comment: If you are on a Mac, you will get an "operation not permitted" on both commands. Ignore the first command, install npm globally with "npm i -g native-run" and just create the symlink as "ln -s <path given by npm root -g>/bin/native-run /usr/local/bin/native-run"

Answer (score 0):

If you do `npm root -g`, it should show you the global path where your packages are getting installed. It points to `NODE_PATH` environment variable. Make sure everything is set right ?

To install any package at a desired path, you go to desired directory & run `npm install package-name`. In your case, go to path `/usr/local/lib/` & run npm install without global option.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue too. I installed npm in .npm-global so the native-run was not found.
I run on this issue by installing native-run in the folder .npm-global and creating the symlink with the command above sudo ln -s /home/user/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/native-run/bin/native-run /usr/bin/native-run

after that I run the command ionic cordova run android

That's it(of course many hours had been lost :-D )

Answer (score 0):

Check your node js path in System variable in an environmental variable.
In my case `C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm` was not addedd to `PATH` for some reason.

[image]